# OpenCV 2.4 Bilateral filtering

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, filtering

In OpenCV android, is it possible to apply bilateral filtering? I know that I can do gaussian blurring like `Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(15,15), 0);` but I cannot seem to find the code for bilateral filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it's possible like:

```
Imgproc.bilateralFilter(mat, dstMat, 10, 50, 0);
```

from [here](http://geekn-nerd.blogspot.com/2012/03/1-opencv-for-android_24.html) and [here](https://github.com/ruimarques/OpenCV-Imgproc/blob/master/OpenCV%20Android%20Tutorial%20-%20Imgproc/src/org/opencv/tutorials/imgproc/MainActivity.java).

**Update**

This:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1376 Process: PID: 30368 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/2_4_pack-android/opencv/modules‌​/imgproc/src/smooth.‌​cpp:1925: error: (-215) (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.type() == dst.type() && src.size() == dst.size() && src.data != dst.data in function void cv::bilateralFilter_8u(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, double, double, int)
```

is because wrong color format of processing `Mat`. You should convert 4 channels `RGBA` format to 3 channels `RGB` for `bilateralFilter()` apply (like in `bilateralFilterTutorial()` method [here](https://github.com/ruimarques/OpenCV-Imgproc/blob/master/OpenCV%20Android%20Tutorial%20-%20Imgproc/src/org/opencv/tutorials/imgproc/MainActivity.java)). So, You code should be like that:

```
// load Mat from somewhere (e.g. from assets)
mSourceImageMat = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.<your_image>);
// convert 4 channel Mat to 3 channel Mat
Imgproc.cvtColor(mSourceImageMat, mSourceImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

// create dest Mat
Mat dstMat = mSourceImageMat.clone();

// apply bilateral filter
Imgproc.bilateralFilter(mSourceImageMat, dstMat, 10, 250, 50);

// convert to 4 channels Mat back
Imgproc.cvtColor(dstMat, dstMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

// create result bitmap and convert Mat to it
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSourceImageMat.cols(), mSourceImageMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(dstMat, bm);

// show bitmap on ImageView
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1376 Process: PID: 30368 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/2_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp:1925: error: (-215) (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3) && src.type() == dst.type() && src.size() == dst.size() && src.data != dst.data in function void cv::bilateralFilter_8u(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, double, double, int)

Comment: Great. The error for me was i was using the same mat, so the check src.data != dst.data was failing. creating a new mat is required for bilateralFilter

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thanks for you answer. I have a question though - why did you first did the channels conversion using BGRA2BGR, and later used RGB2RGBA (I'd expect that in the second time you'd use BGR2BGRA). I'm not very familiar with opencv yet, so I'd like to understand that. thanks again.

Comment: @noamgot Hmm, seems it is my mistake. It's important 3 channels `Mat` for `Imgproc.bilateralFilter()`, but channels order is not important (actually, it's just matrix of numbers). May be with `BGRA2BGR->BGR2BGRA` you'll got better results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be, that you use PNG image, which has a 4th channel for transparency. Convert it from 4 channel to 3 channel, before use.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src,dst,Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```